# WebExtensions to cache a config / refresh it daily

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am currently developing a WebExtensions (Firefox + Chrome) which goal is to display a custom message on top of some websites indicating that users should access them using a specific URL (via a proxy) to get full access to content (I am working for a university and if users want to read full text of papers we have purchased for them, they need to pass through our [EZProxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EZproxy) server).

The thing is that the list of resources is changing, with new subscriptions for example, and I'd like my extension to be aware of this list. I can serve it as JSON from my server but I need my extension to regularly check this json and acts accordingly.

At the moment the code I have written, `ezproxy.js` is defined in manifest.json as :

```
"content_scripts": [
{ 
  "matches": [
    "*://*/*"
  ], 
  "js" : [
    "ezproxy.js"
  ]
}
]
```

I am not sure it is the best way because it will run on any website, even if only ~100 domains are concerned. But as I don't want to update my extension each time a new domain is added/removed I can't think of any other option. Anything I have missed?

With this `manifest.json`, my pseudo-code is looking as :

```
var host = window.location.host;
for ( var domain in <MYLIST> )
{
  if ( RegExp(domain + "$").test(host) )
  {
     // Display the message
  }
}
```

I am thinking about using [Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage) with serialized data but I am wondering how to make sure that my local storage is regularly updated. What is the easiest way in a web extension to run each 24hours a test against a server to update the local storage?

And if this is the best way

Comment: You can make your extension fetch the list from your server upon each launch.

Comment: [declarativeContent API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) + [alarms API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms), see also [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).